# Avoiding being blocked for suggesting new ideas

Tags: discussion, down-votes

On SO meta a while back I complained about the way downvoting worked because many people were downvoting legitimate, high-quality questions, for other reasons. Usually they didn't either like the idea being proposed, or they didn't like the subject of the post even being discussed because it deviated from the status quo.

The response to this was that I shouldn't take it personally, and that the votes in no way reflected the quality of the post, but were just indicative that the readers disagreed in one way or another with the question or suggestions in the question. They seemed to think this was perfectly normal and ok and conducive to further discussion.

Well, now after proposing an idea, which I thought merited discussion, that was disliked to the tune of -22, I am getting a warning "you are in danger of being blocked from asking anymore".

I thought the purpose of meta was to **discuss** things and consider new ideas. If everyone who proposes new ideas, gets dozens of downvotes from the status quo crowd, then I would think that would have the effect of discouraging new ideas, or simply banning people who propose new ideas, as appears to be happening to me. The effect of this may be that by a Darwinian process meta participation will be limited to people who like the status quo, and outsiders with new ideas will be greated with hostily and rejection.

Anyway, as this post falls into the category of "things disturbing the status quo" it will probably be given another twenty downvotes, so I will be banned. Thanks for letting me participate while it lasted, and goodbye.

Comment: I think the attitude you've had speaks volumes as far as explanation. Others have said some of the same things you've said - just constructively - and not been voted down nearly as much.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Well, regardless of what criteria you are banning people, it has the effect of shrinking the community to sort of a group of cheerleaders. Is that your message? We only want people to participate in meta if they have the "right attitude"? Everyone has to pass your careful psychological screening process or they get banned? Did you know there were only 40 voters this week on Meta total? Why do you think that is? It is because you keep hammering newbies with downvotes for any one of 20 different reasons, mine being "I don't have the right attitude"?

Comment: **"Is that your message? We only want people to participate in meta if they have the "right attitude"?"** It seems you understand, now.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato I am not an idiot, of course I understand. I am just pointing out you are turning Meta into a tiny club of self-reinforcing people all sharing the same opinions, and that is not conducive to growth or change.

Comment: Since you insist on conflating content with presentation, I'm done.

Comment: I see no posts on your [MSO account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1655700/tyler-durden). Just be aware that deleting too many posts also leads to a post ban.

Comment: @AsheeshR That is because all my posts got deleted by someone else, probably in some kind of system sweep. I did not delete any of my own SO Meta posts. As you can see I have the Yearling badge which requires 200 rep which is proof that I had made successful posts there.

Comment: Its not so much *what* you're saying, as *how* you're saying it. Meta doesn't mind criticism, so long as its *constructive*. If all you want to do is rant (which is what this is, albeit pretty calm for a rant), then this isn't the place for you. If you have a point, make it as constructively as you can. We don't like, "You guys are censoring criticism" any more than others do. Going, "Hey, this could be a problem, what do you think" is *much* more constructive.

Comment: There are actually a lot of people that agree with you, but people are turned off because you structured your question like a rant. Want to see a *constructive* way to post this question? See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually Same question, phrased constructively. 132 upvotes. Also, I voted to close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @fbueckert This is not just about rants. Look through the posts to Meta and see how many negative scores there are. There are 15 different reasons why they are getting downvoted, not just because they are "ranting". The point is simple: legitimate posts are getting downvoted and it is driving away divergence of opinion. You can justify your downvotes however you want, but regardless the EFFECT is your community is becoming increasingly smaller, incestuous, self-reinforcing and intolerant of criticism. As I said above the result is perpetuation of the status quo and resistance to change.

Comment: And your attitude shows exactly why you're getting such a chilly reception; you are attacking the aspects you don't like with strawmen.  If you want to be welcomed (and trust me, we welcome constructive criticism), you yourself have to be receptive to perhaps being wrong.  Nowhere in this are you saying, "Oh, hey, maybe they have a point."; it's all, "What they're doing is bad, and needs to change".  The message can be the same, at it's bare bones, but the *focus* of how it is said matters as much, or more, as *what* is said.

Comment: @TylerDurden I realize you've made up your mind whatever justification we give you. But can you back up the following assertion? "Some users have the idea that under no circumstances should the language be put in the title of a question." If you can't back up that assertion with an actual reference, then don't count on my upvote. If you're going to summarize other people's opinions, then by all means, do it, but please post an actual reference of what that person said. Hopefully, you're able to edit your own existing questions? Or am I wrong to think that?

Answer (score 10):

I believe there are two main scenarios that typically end badly for the asker around meta:

1. Ideas that seem awesome on the surface, but have been discussed a number of times over the years and/or turned out not to be all that great in practice. Typical examples include "let's not require reputation to comment" or "why am I blocked from asking questions? by the way, I didn't read the error message I got."

   The former can be overcome by addressing the previous objections in the question itself to spark a new discussion instead of rehashing the same ol', same ol' stuff. The latter is usually resolved by a pointer to an existing help article or question.
2. *How* you phrase your ideas overshadows *what* they are. Like it or not, you're speaking to a community of people here. Sure, you can<sup>*</sup> call folks names or accuse them of various abuses and then be surprised that they for some odd reason aren't receptive to your ideas, but that sounds like a waste of your time more than anything.

   Take the time to focus on examples of problems you're seeing over specific users or moderators and you may find that your suggestions go over a bit better. Individual incidents with users can be reported to moderators via flags; problems with moderator actions can be reported to Stack Exchange via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page if your issue can't be resolved by the community or another moderator after a (constructive) appeal on the site's meta.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Up to a point. You don't have to kowtow to everyone, but [basic civility requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) are in effect.</sub>

---

In the case of [the idea you mentioned as an example here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233698/stealth-censorship-of-comments-immunity), it's really the difference between "can I get a notification when my comment is deleted?" and "moderators are censoring me!".

I can't guarantee that the former would get much support. However, you effectively said the latter and I can see why many would bristle at that. Nobody knows who you are. Nobody is going out of their way to oppress you around here. Take a step back, focus on the problem you're trying to address, read previous discussions (if any), and things are likely to go much better for you.

---

See also: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)